# WooCommerce:how to add custom checkmarks in checkout page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to add 4 checkmarks to the checkout page.Here in this block

[image]

The selected values ​​should be displayed further and also in orders in the admin panel. I'm new to php.I found that a checkmark can be added using woocommerce_wp_checkbox.My code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'my_custom_checkout_field');

function my_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {

    echo '<div id="my-new-field"><h3>'.__('Please select values: ').'</h3>';

    woocommerce_form_field( 'my_checkbox', array(
        'type'          => 'checkbox',
        'class'         => array('input-checkbox'),
        'label'         => __('Values1.'),
        'required'  => true,
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'my_checkbox' ));

    echo '</div>';
}


add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_custom_checkout_field_process');

function my_custom_checkout_field_process() {
    global $woocommerce;

    // Check if set, if its not set add an error.
    if (!$_POST['my_checkbox'])
         $woocommerce->add_error( __('Please agree to my checkbox.') );
}
    add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta');

function my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
    if ($_POST['my_checkbox']) update_post_meta( $order_id, 'My Checkbox', esc_attr($_POST['my_checkbox']));
}
```

But how I can add 4 check marks and then process the selected value?